# Axios PUT request to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, put

I read the documentation on axios on PUT request and it seems similar to a GET request. However, there wasn't an example code like GET, but I assume it is similar to how to do a GET request. I seem to have issue making a PUT request using axios. This is what I have so far with a test server that I am using:

```
axios.put('http://localhost:8080/cats')
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      cat: res
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Basically, I am trying to select an item and make changes to it.

Comment: with a `PUT`, one would expect some data to *put* ... `I seem to have issue` what is the issue? and error? a warning? your dog ran away?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you don't mention the error so we can not know what is wrong.

Comment: BTW your strurcture must be like this `// Send a PUT request 
axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/cats',
  data: {
    data: 'some data here'
  }
});` Check this web for more info [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 23):

I think you don't understand how Axios and HTTP requests work. When making a PUT request, you have to send the data you want to "put" into the item. You seem to think that when you make a PUT request you will receive the item back which you can then edit and have it save automatically, which is not true.

Image that you had a whole bunch of cats, and they had names, images, and descriptions about them. Now say you want to update the name of the cat which is identified by the number 1 (that's its ID).

Here is an example of using a PUT request (through Axios) to update that cat's name:

```
axios.put('https://example.com/cats/1', {
    name: 'Tophat Cat'
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

See how I had to specify which cat I wanted to update (by providing the unique URL for that cat) and also supply the specific data I want updated (the name)? Now it would be up to your server to see that it received a PUT request for the first cat, and that the data says to update the name to "Tophat Cat".

Then the server would send a response (it could be anything from "The update was successful." to a JSON representation of the updated cat's data.

Remember, a PUT request should only be used for updating data that already exists. If you want to add new data (which is what it looks like a little bit in your example, since you were pointing the request to just `/cats` without an ID), you should instead use a POST request. POST requests are intended for *adding new data* and PUT requests are intended for *updating existing data*.

The POST request would look very similar to the PUT request example above, but with some important changes:

```
axios.post('https://example.com/cats', {
    name: 'Catsandra',
    image: 'https://example.com/images/catsandra.jpg',
    description: 'Catsandra is the fanciest cat in town!'
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Now the request is going to just `/cats` which is typical in a REST API (it can't be pointed at a specific cat ID because the cat doesn't exist yet). It also specifies *all* the data needed to create a new cat. In the PUT request we only included what we wanted to update. In a POST request the other data doesn't exist yet so we have to specify everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import   { Axios } from 'axios';

 Axios.put('http://localhost:8080/cats')
.then(res => {
 this.setState({
   cat: res
  });
})
   .catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
 })
```